# Xen dom0 crashed

Tags: linux, centos, xen, linux-networking, linux-kernel

Lots of questions this week,

I got this error on dom0, then the server crashed (according to /var/log/messages):

```
Jun 22 10:02:09 453 dhcpd: DHCPACK to xx.xxx.xxx.xx (xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx) via eth0
Jun 22 10:02:10 453 kernel: list_add corruption. prev->next should be ffff880007b111d8, but was ffff880007b01218
Jun 22 10:02:10 453 kernel: ----------- [cut here ] --------- [please bite here ] ---------
Jun 22 10:02:10 453 kernel: Kernel BUG at lib/list_debug.c:31
Jun 22 10:02:10 453 kernel: invalid opcode: 0000 [1] SMP
Jun 22 10:02:10 453 kernel: last sysfs file: /devices/xen-backend/vbd-2-2049/statistics/wr_sect
```

Server is on CentOS 5.8

```
/boot/grub/grub.conf
title CentOS (2.6.18-274.17.1.el5xen)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /boot/xen.gz-4.1.1 dom0_mem=2048m pci=nomsi
        module /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.18-274.17.1.el5xen ro root=LABEL=/ pci=nomsi
        module /boot/initrd-2.6.18-274.17.1.el5xen.img
```

Comment: Are you using some dodgy devices like USB?

Comment: We have a KVM connected to it. It has been there for several months.

I have rebooted the server with irqpoll added to grub.conf.

Answer (score 0):

First - why are you using your Dom0 as DHCP-server?

Second - looks like a memory fault to me.